# Can we allow reviewers to view deleted comments on a question they are reviewing?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

When deciding what action to take on a question in the Review Queues, particularly suggested edits, it would be very helpful to be able to view any deleted comments on that question.

To be clear, I am proposing adding the ability to view deleted comments *only* for the question *currently* being reviewed.

My justification for this is for reviews like this;

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23550472

I can see that a lot of extra information was added to this question  <s>that was not added by the OP</s>. From the context of the added info, it seems as if it was a comment (that is no longer there);

> I expect the output to be like only one date should get clicked not
>   the entire grid.After clicking on a date i can handle events. but now
>   if i click anywhere inside grid, the function is getting called. If
>   needed I can provide my CSS code. but any solution on this?

My gut reaction to this was to decline the edit (It first appeared like it might be spam). I looked at the edit comment which just says: *code separating*. It then occurred to me that this might have been in a comment posted by the op, which the editor has deleted and moved to the question.

However, without being able to verify this - I'm not sure whether to approve or not. Ideally, this would have been in the edit comment.

### Update

It has been pointed out to me that this was indeed there originally - I missed it in the output view as it was part of the code block. Still, I suppose this would still be a useful feature, just perhaps not on this occasion.

I'll still leave this question here so there's a reference for anybody else asking a similar thing in the future.

Comment: Wow, my bad. It was in a code block in the output view and I missed it totally.

Comment: What's going on with that strikethrough text?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Is that better? I didn't know at first you could use <s> to do it so it came from unicode.

Comment: Much better. It made me uncomfortable reading it previously 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cases where it looks like one person is taking action on a post that the post owner really should be taking (this comes in a few variants):

- User 1 is named "Foo" and User 2 is named "Foo", but one can't seem to edit the post directly and had to suggest an edit to it
- User 1 is named "Foo" and User 2 is named "Bar", but is suggesting an edit that seems to contain knowledge only the post owner could have

... then it's *very* likely that we have a case of someone accidentally creating multiple accounts and trying to edit their previous posts from the wrong one. At that point, I recommend dropping out of the review and taking a closer look (also see if some answers exist that were intended to be comments) and throw some flags down for moderators to have a look.

That's not what happened in this case (although it wasn't immediately obvious). Here, someone just fished the OP's own language out of a code block and formatted it, but the presentation should trigger the same instinct.

This was a pretty rampant problem before we forced registration in order to ask, people kept becoming disenfranchised from their contributions whenever they'd lose the cookie tying them to the unregistered account. But, it still does happen when people use multiple credentials when signing up, and (occasionally) forget to register after writing a few answers they later want to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

For FR itself - no, I don't see how seeing deleted comments could help you decide fate of the edit.

The only comments that *may* be useful are the once that should only be deleted after edit is approved as "no longer needed". The rest are unlikely help for review - I don't see how "those @#$@ can't #@$# understand my clear question and @#$@ try to change it" type of comments (the once that are getting deleted quickly enough to happen before edit reviewed) would help.

- spam, harassment, unkind - if you need this type of comments to make decision whether review is useful you are definitely doing it wrong. None on comments deleted for these reasons should impact how you look at the content. Seeing such comments will likely have negative impact on quality of the review or health of the reviewer.
- no longer needed - comment deleted for this reason should not apply to the current edit. One is expected to flag only when comment no longer applies to the post at the moment of flagging. In unlikely case the editor themselves flagged comment they are editing into the post before edit got approved I hope moderators will see that edit is not yet applied and decline flag (or maybe approve the edit first). Also I expect some noticeable time to pass for this type of flags to be acted upon - more then typical review timeframe.
- moderator attention - I personally don't expect such flags to be used on clarification comments (the kind you may be interested in review) but rather comments that have other problems. Moderators are even more likely to look at the post and hopefully notice if comment is important for current state of the post.

Comment: Fair enough. It just seems to me that reviewers shouldn’t be working with a half empty toolbox. In the example above, being able to see comments may have helped to determine if an edit was on topic - although I suppose only in the event that useful comments were deleted _before_ the edit, which as you say shouldn’t be the case.